# Can't delete the Row of DataBase from Custom ListView via Context Menu inside of Fragment - Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've added data into my SQLite database, and it shows inside listView.
But I want to delete it with Context menu.
Context menu is showing, but data is not deleted.

Here is sample of my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    mDataBase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete:

            mDataBase.delete("orderTable", "_id" + " =? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(info.id)});

            dbAdaper.setArrayMyData(selectAll());
            dbAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mDataBase.close();

    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

I found out that info.id has 0 value.

```
 dbAdaper = new DBBasketAdapter(getActivity(), selectAll());
    listView.setAdapter(dbAdaper);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code converts the ID into a string.

For integers, using SQL parameters is not necessary; just use the value directly:

```
mDataBase.delete("orderTable", "_id = " + info.id, null);
```

Comment: I hate passing values directly in statements!!! But I must aggree with you, as workaround for handling `String [] whereArgs` is worthless...